# How do I know the type of a function parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function f(a, b) {}
```

Taking a sample function *f* in javascript, how do I know how objects *a* and *b* should look like ?

In Java for example, the class is self-documenting the expected object:

```
class A {
   private int c;
   private String d;
   private E e;
}
```

But how do I create the object in javascript, not knowing how it should look like, but making it valid for the function to run properly ?

The function *f* can be from a 3rd party lib, another module from the project ...

Comment: By reading the documentation? In your Java example, how do you know what the permissible range of values for `int c` is? Or what the semantic meaning of `String d` is?

Comment: Check out TypeScript if you would like strong typing at development time

Comment: @JaredSmith variables usually have suggestive names. I would avoid writing documentation for every function, it's a lot to maintain (high risk of going out of sync also)

Comment: @FrankModica yes, that would be helpful, but I'm trying to find a best practice for ES6

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea yeah, I get that you picked one character names because it's an example. My point though is that it *isn't enough*. There are things, important things, about the code that aren't conveyed by the type or variable name. You still have to have documentation, you still have to read it, etc. etc. The real question you have seems to be "how can I have compiler-checked metadata for my JavaScript code?" and the only answer is to use a static analyzer like flow or google closure. Or switch to TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language. It does not enforce types for function parameters.

If you want to know what values a function expects to be passed to it you have two basic options:

- Read the documentation for the function
- Read the source code of the function

Comment: The documentation can be missing or out of sync and going through the source code of a 3rd party lib seems something to be avoided (I want to use its API, without concern of the implementation). Is there a tool which generates automatic documentation for the function parameters ?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea — Given Jared's comment and the first sentence of this answer, what do you expect such a tool to do beyond listing the variable names used for the parameters? (Also keep in mind that variable names may be minified, or not be used in favour of the `arguments` object).

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea - If you want strictly typed parameters (which it sounds like you do), then Javascript is not for you.  If you control the code, then you can use TypeScript and compile to Javascript, but otherwise, you do what Quentin suggested - read the doc or look at the code.  There are no other choices.  It is NOT something that can be collected by a tool automatically.  There can even be Javascript functions that accept multiple types in a specific argument.  The language is dynamically typed, not statically typed.

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea It may also be worth remembering that JavaScript does not support overloading of methods based on argument type, because function objects do not have compile time signatures.  Any "pseudo-overloading" must be implemented at run time by function code examining the type and/or value of arguments passed and dynamically varying processing based upon actual argument values.